# What is the simplest syntax for Iverson bracket in XPath?

Tags: xpath

I would like to use Iverson bracket (ie. mapping true => 1, false => 0) in the XPath expression.

Example: instead of writing

```
someNumber+(if(elem1/elem2[@attr='123'])then(1)else(0)))*someOtherNumber
```

I would like to write (but somehow without the "Iverson")

```
someNumber+Iverson(elem1/elem2[@attr='123'])*someOtherNumber
```

The following doesn't work:

```
someNumber+[elem1/elem2[@attr='123']]*someOtherNumber
```

Casting to boolean works:

```
someNumber+boolean(elem1/elem2[@attr='123'])*someOtherNumber
```

Is there a more simple syntax than "if(...)then(1)else(0)" or "boolean(...)"?

Comment: _"Casting to boolean works:"_ >> you aren't casting to a boolean, that would be `expr cast as xs:boolean`. The `fn:boolean` does a lot more and calculates the EBV. Casting does not and would fail in many cases where the function would succeed.

Comment: In the XPath and XQuery Functions specification the first paragraph of the Casting chapter states that the constructor function and casting have "identical semantics and different syntax". It seems I have mixed up `fn:boolean` and `xs:boolean`, which are two different things.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#casting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Iverson

Interestingly, in XPath you already use a version of the [Iverson bracket syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) with predicates in `[@attr='123']` or `[@attr]`, which returns true if its EBV is true. But if it evaluates to a number, it will return the n<sup>th</sup> item from the sequence.

For the discussion, let's replace your expression `elem1/elem2[@attr='123']` with `EXPR` for brevity, and the rest like:

```
X + EXPR * Y
```

Where the idea is to get as close as possible to the Iverson syntax for EXPR.

#### XPath 2.0

Your expression requires less parentheses:

> ```
> X + if(EXPR) then 1 else 0 * Y
> ```

This can also be written as the following, assuming false-value of `EXPR` is an empty sequence:

```
X + (EXPR, 1, 0)[2] * Y
```

> Is there a more simple syntax than "boolean(...)"?

You suggested the `boolean(EXPR)` function, but as you mentioned in the comments, this will not work, you need to convert it to a number, for instance with:

```
X + number(boolean(EXPR)) * Y
```

I think the shortest version in XPath 2.0 is the empty-sequence dismissal approach, but it may not always work, it requires the first item to return the empty sequence.

If you have a validating processor that sets the element as boolean, you can use:

```
X + number(EXPR) * Y
```

Or if typed as a number with valid values 0 and 1, just:

```
EXPR
```

#### XPath 3.0

Let's see if with the new XPath 3.0 syntax we can get even simpler:

```
let $Iv := function($i) { number(boolean($i)) }
return X + $Iv(EXPR) * Y
```

With XQuery and XSLT, but also XPath, you can declare this variable globally, which changes the expression into:

```
X + $Yv(EXPR) * Y
```

But you'll still have to deal with the parentheses, but keep reading...

#### XPath 3.1

In 3.1, the [arrow operator has been introduced](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrow-operator), which allows your original example to be written as:

```
X + EXPR=>boolean()=>number() * Y
```

Given that we now have a global variable with a function item, we can do:

```
X + EXPR=>$Iv() * Y
```

#### Other approach

Since setting a global variable to an anonymous function is nothing more than creating a function, we can also declare a function in XQuery or XSLT. Something like:

```
X + EXPR=>i:v() * Y
```

Comment: By "false" I mean that the effective boolean value (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-ebv) of the expression is false (anything that can be passed as a test expression to the if instruction).

Comment: @tafit3, if you require that restriction, then the shortcut I proposed won't help, because the only sure-fire way of getting the EBV is, you guessed it, `fn:boolean`. However, if you want to do it without that, you can use an XSD and a validating processor, which will use the type of the node, which will then be boolean, and you do not need to use the `fn:boolean` function anymore.

Comment: @tafit3, if you can switch to a more recent version of XPath, you can use the new arrow operator or function items, which may help you in writing this "simpler" ;).

Comment: you have convinced me that in XPath 2.0 there is no simpler way than invoking `fn:boolean`. I don't have a schema-aware XPath processor (I use saxon). I don't like `if(x)then(1)else(0)` and `(x,1,0)[2]`. The `(x=>$b())*3` is only 1 character shorter than `boolean(x)*3`. BTW, I checked that in XQuery the `fn:boolean` is not enough and you have to do `number(boolean(...))` in order to get the same result, otherwise you get the error "Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types (xs:boolean, xs:integer)". I thought XPath and XQuery would behave the same in such a simple case.

Comment: @tafit3, yes you are right, that is an error, but in XPath, not in XQuery. Unless with XPath you mean 1.0, which was less type-safe in this respect. I didn't consider it in my answer though, but `number(boolean(...))` suggests that setting a (global) variable as a function item will make it shorter. Also, you will find the syntax (a, b, c)[1] used _a lot_ in XPath 2.0+ and XSLT 2.0+ code, it is the simplest, and still readable version available. But you are right, it is not _true Iversion_.

Comment: @tafit3, I have updated the question. Obviously, creating a function will yield the fewest keystrokes, unless you can use a validating processor. With that, I got it down to 4 keystrokes (still twice as much as the two keystrokes for Iverson).